# How to find the position in the list variable, searched by string [Python]

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
result = ['Alice in the forest - 01.mp4', 'Code-009 - 02.mp4', 'Art 7 - 01.mp4', 'Will be owned - 05.mp4']
```

and a variable like this

```
search = 'Alice'
```

Is there a way to search through the list and find `'Alice in the forest - 01.mp4'` by keyword `'Alice'` and save the numbering of the variable in the list?

P.s: Until now, I was trying with `string=re.compile("Alice")`. Didn't print out a thing though.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by *"save the numbering of the variable in the list"*?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Wanted to find the position with in the list  ex) Alice in the forest = 0, Code-009 = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the strings that contain your search term, you can use:

```
match_string = [s for s in result if "Alice" in s]
```

To get the positions of all the strings that contain your search term, you can use:

```
match_string = [i for i, s in enumerate(result) if "Alice" in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through list and find whether your search word occurs in the current item.

```
def searchWordInList(input_list, word):
    index_and_value = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        if word in input_list[i]:
            index_and_value .append(i, input_list[i])
    return index_and_value 
result = ['Alice in the forest - 01.mp4', 'Code-009 - 02.mp4', 'Art 7 - 01.mp4', 'Will be owned - 05.mp4']
search = 'Alice'

index_and_value = searchWordInList(result, search)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the [`filter`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) and [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html#) function:

```
result = ['Alice in the forest - 01.mp4', 'Code-009 - 02.mp4', 'Art 7 - 01.mp4', 'Will be owned - 05.mp4']
search = 'Alice'
output = list(filter(lambda song: search in song[1], enumerate(result)))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'Alice in the forest - 01.mp4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
word1='Alice'
result = ['Alice in the forest - 01.mp4', 'Code-009 - 02.mp4', 'Art 7 - 01.mp4', 'Will be owned - 05.mp4']
for i, j in enumerate(result):
    if word1 in j:
        print i
```

enumerate() returns all index occurrences of "Alice'